# Mozilla not firing iceCandidate using kurento media server (one-2-many example)

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, kurento

I'm trying one-2-many example of Kurento media server,it is always returning null candidate on mozilla firefox, but same piece of code working fine on google chrome.

As i had put an alert onicecandidate event

```
pc.addEventListener('icecandidate', function (event) {
        var candidate = event.candidate;
        alert("Candidate ==== "+candidate);
});
```

It is returning null candidate. I'm using firefox 24.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585837/icecandidate-returning-null-on-mozilla-firefox-26-0) that recommends to update the browser, version 24 is too old.